# Custom Function with cell reference inputs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to excel custom functions and trying to create a custom Excel function that outputs a "Y" or "N" and takes four arguments. The error I'm getting on the other end is #VALUE! with no further explanation. I tried looking at the Range object in the MSDN docs and can't understand why my function isn't reading the values.

My function takes four arguments and the datatypes in the cells are median: Double, base: Double, hours: Integer, and exemption: String (it takes a letter "E" or "N"). I get those arguments from four separate cells in my worksheet.

```
Function ToIncrease(median As Range, base As Range, hours As Range, exemption As Range)

    ToIncrease = "N"
    exempt = exemption.Value

    If exempt.Equals("N") Then
        baseSal = base.Value * hours.Value
        medianSal = median.Value * hours.Value
        If medianSal > baseSal Then
            ToIncrease = "Y"
            End If
    End If

    If exempt.Equals("E") Then
        If median.Value > base.Value Then
            ToIncrease = "Y"
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

I first tried `exemption.Value.Equals("N")` and it didn't work, and then I tried to declare the exempt variable as `Dim exempt As String = exemption.Value` and got an error about expecting the end of a statement.

Comment: `If exempt.value = "N" Then` and the same with the other IF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace lines like:

```
If exempt.Equals("N") Then
```

with

```
If exempt = "N" Then
```

*(there may be other problems as well)*

It is MUCH easier to debug VBA code as a `Sub` rather than a `Function()` because the error messages are much better.

Comment: thanks, that was it. i was so convinced that i had to use a string method and was just hoping it read it as such like in javascript.